# Incorrect Syntax Near 'Begin'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have error :
Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure v_gameTypes, Line 125
Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'. If i did it with PROC there will be no errors Here is the code

```
CREATE FUNCTION v_gameTypes
(@game_ID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
IF( EXISTS(SELECT*FROM Strategies WHERE Strategies.game = @game_ID))
RETURN  SELECT Strategies.real_time FROM Strategies WHERE Strategies.game = @game_ID

IF( EXISTS(SELECT*FROM Actions WHERE Actions.game = @game_ID))
RETURN  SELECT Actions.sub_genre FROM Actions WHERE Actions.game = @game_ID

IF( EXISTS(SELECT*FROM Sports WHERE Sports.game = @game_ID))
RETURN  SELECT Sports.s_type FROM Sports WHERE Sports.game = @game_ID

RETURN  SELECT RPGs.story_line, RPGs.PvP FROM RPGs WHERE RPGs.game = @game_ID
END
GO
```

Comment: Shouldn't the table return type specify the columns to return? `RETURNS TABLE (...) AS ...` ?

Comment: Nope, this is not the problem i have another functions that returns table but without any if statements

Comment: You don't need to specify columns if you do a `AS RETURN (SELECT...)`, but you should specify columns if you have statements, and you should specify which local table variable that will hold the results. You should check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) for details. Your function does not follow any of the definitions, you most likely want the "Multistatement Table-valued Function Syntax" definition, which requires both the column specification and a local variable. The `RETURN SELECT` syntax is only in the single inline table function.